# TypeError: Cannot read property 'isCompleted' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Why is it undefined? when I tried to console log the foundTodo variable it will display undefine everytime I clicked the task.

```
const todos = [
{
    task: 'watching react tuts',
    isCompleted: true
},
{
    task: 'eat dinner',
    isCompleted: false
}
];


App.js
        toggleTask(task) {
        const foundTodo = _.find(this.state.todos, todo => task.todo == task);

        foundTodo.isCompleted = !foundTodo.isCompleted;
        this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos });
      }
```

[image]

I'm new to react...so I try to create a todos app.

Comment: If you want to change the `foundTodo`, then remove `const`  and use `var` or `let` ,Please also post the `console.log(foundTodo);`;

Comment: still the error is undefined when using let or var! this code will do the onClick `onClick={this.props.toggleTask.bind(this, task)}>`

Comment: console.log(foundTodo); ?

Comment: You are comparing `task.todo` and `task`. Should the param be named `todo` or should you compare `task === task`? It would also help with more of your app. THe problem could also be that you haven't bound the event handler correctly.

Comment: @amcdrmtt yes, I already changed that to `==` and `===` still undefined error

Comment: I am not saying try console.log(foundTodo); , I want you to post output of console.log(foundTodo); in question.

Comment: @dextree, please read my first comment carefully.

Comment: @dextree I'm not suggesting `===`. I'm asking if you are comparing the correct variables? You are comparing `task.todo` with `task`. Should you be comparing `task` with `task`? Or is the input parameter named poorly (and should be named `todo`)?

Comment: @amcdrmtt the logic here is that find the todo task that matches were passing in which is task that we clicked, thats why I used this `===`

Comment: @VivekDoshi I updated the question with an image above that's the output of `foundTodo` after I clicked the task but when I tried to `console.log(task)` it will display the task that I clicked.

Comment: @dextree, OMG , please also post the values of `this.state.todos` and `task`

Comment: Can you please add a runnable example that demonstrates the error?

Answer (score 1):

Just change :

```
todo => task.todo == task
```

to

```
todo => todo.task == task
```

Comment: this works on me also, sorry I was a beginner on this framework. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the code in your example is exactly what you have in your application, then it is probably due to bad variable naming. You have:

```
toggleTask(task) {
  const foundTodo = _.find(this.state.todos, todo => task.todo == task);
  ..
}
```

In your arrow function `todo` is the param, but then you do `task.todo == task`.

It probably should be:

```
toggleTask(task) {
  const foundTodo = _.find(this.state.todos, todo => todo.task == task);
  ..
}
```

Comment: yeah I get it now, just the naming convention that I made wrong. Thanks!